# AWS Autoscaling Mixed Instance Types vs. EC2 Fleet Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

With the release of mixed instance types in AWS AutoScaling, are there still advantages to using EC2 Fleet? Let's also not consider the differences in Reserved Instances and Weighting since Jeff Barr's mixed instance type announcement says that RIs and weighting will be released in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/scale-instances-across-purchase-options-in-a-single-ASG/) says

> Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling now lets you provision and automatically scale
>   instances across purchase options, Availability Zones (AZ), and
>   instance families in a single Auto Scaling group (ASG), to optimize
>   scale, performance, and cost. Now you can include Spot Instances with
>   On-Demand and RIs in a single ASG, to save up to 90% on compute.
>
> Earlier this year, we announced EC2 Fleet, an API to provision
>   capacity across purchase options, AZs and instance types. Now this EC2
>   Fleet functionality is available via EC2 Auto Scaling. Powered by EC2
>   Fleet, you can now create an ASG by defining which EC2 instance types
>   work for you and how much of the desired capacity should be filled
>   using On-Demand, RI and Spot purchase options. EC2 Auto Scaling
>   continues to optimize and maintain the mix as and when the ASG scales
>   out or scales back, simplifying capacity provisioning and cost
>   optimization with automatic scaling across instances and purchase
>   options. EC2 Auto Scaling also continues to provide lifecycle hooks,
>   instance health checks and scheduled scaling to automate capacity
>   management.

Based on that I think they've simply exposed EC2 Fleet features inside an auto-scaling group - ie the same functionality with a different interface. I expect there is now a much reduced need for EC2 fleet, unless the interface exposes additional options not given in the auto-scaling group interface.